# JSON: Parsing JSON string with json.loads gets error: Expecting , delimiter:

Tags: python, json, parsing

The JSON string below get error:
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column ....

```
{"EndUsrIpAdr":"x.x.x.x","EndUsrBrwsrAgnt":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; Bush Spira E2X 5" Smartphone Build/LMY47D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36","ReqOrg":"xxx.com"}
```

Modifying `E2X 5"` to `E2X 5` solves the error.

How I can remove this `"` from : `E2X 5"` , because if I use replace, I am afraid it will remove all "" from the JSON string.

Comment: Escape it using `\"`. See https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: It is not a manually created string. Data is coming from DB and stored in variable.

Comment: Whatever is producing the JSON is doing so incorrectly and needs to be fixed.

Comment: I would suggest you get the source of the invalid JSON fixed. To fix it on your side for all possible occasion of rogue quotation marks, you have to find a pattern first to identify it. One example is not enough for that.

Comment: Thank you Ryan & Klaus D. I was thinking the same. Source of invalid JSON should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Its an invalid JSON, you can validate your json here https://jsonlint.com

You can use `\"` delimiter to add `"` or any other escape character

Here is python sample code to parse son

```
import json
with open("jsonFileName.json") as _fp:
    try:
        _json_data = json.load(_fp)
        # _json_data is a python dict, if everything went correct
    except:
        # error in parsing son
        pass
```